# How do I instrument code coverage for JMockit where src code is a dependency?

Tags: code-coverage, jmockit

I have a maven project for tests where src code is complied into classes and made available as a dependency. Now I need to write tests with JMockit and get code coverage reports.

Based on the documentation(http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html) I won't be able to get coverage where src files are .class files in a jar. How do I handle that situation?

I'm open to use any code coverage tool as long as it works with JMockit.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML coverage report will include any classes for which the sources can be found. You can list all source directories to be searched by setting the `coverage-srcDirs` system property (see list of all properties in http://jmockit.org/tutorial/CodeCoverage.html#configuration).

Also, if the classes of some dependency are in a jar file, then they'll need to be selected in the `coverage-classes` property (since classes from jar files are left out by default).